# Why wasn't the U.S. keen in having Saudi Arabia develop nuclear power despite being a reliable ally of the U.S. for so long?

Tags: united-states, saudi-arabia

> Asked whether the question of eroding Israel’s “security” included
> Riyadh establishing a civilian nuclear programme on its soil, Hanegbi
> said that for that, Israel’s consent was not needed.
>
> “Dozens of countries operate projects with civilian nuclear cores, and
> with nuclear endeavours for energy, this is not something that
> endangers them nor their neighbours,” he said.

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/7/31/road-to-normalising-ties-with-saudi-arabia-still-long-israeli-official

Why wasn't the U.S. keen in having Saudi Arabia develop nuclear power despite being a reliable ally of the U.S. for so long, especially with allies such as Japan and South Korea being allowed to develop nuclear power for many years? I am trying to understand why they didn't consider allowing them to develop it a long time ago. What are all the negative outcomes that could come from allowing Saudi Arabia to develop nuclear power?

Comment: This [answer to a related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/30400/41875) has some content about the US's apparent view on Saudi nuclear power (toward the end, after the part about Saudi getting nukes).

Answer (score 4):

Because some fear it could lead to a nuclear arms race in the middle east.

[U.S. approved secret nuclear power work for Saudi Arabia](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-saudi-nuclear/u-s-approved-secret-nuclear-power-work-for-saudi-arabia-idUSKCN1R82MG)

> Many U.S. lawmakers are concerned that sharing nuclear technology with Saudi Arabia could eventually lead to a nuclear arms race in the Middle East.

While they may be a longstanding ally there are concerns that them having a nuclear power could result in more turmoil in the middle east.